# How to improve Pandas GroupBy Transform functionality for bulk transforming to multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to add 9 columns to my Pandas DataFrame consisting of the following information:

- The sum of the transactions this day/week/month (AmtDay/AmtWeek/AmtMonth)
- The count of transactions this day/week/month (CountDay/CountWeek/CountMonth)
- The average amount of the transactions this day/week/month (AvgAmtDay/AvgAmtWeek/AvgAmtMonth)

To do this I've written the following code:

```
df["AmtDay"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year","Day"])["Amount"].transform(sum)
df["CountDay"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Day"])["Amount"].transform(len)
df["AvgAmtDay"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Day"])["Amount"].transform(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x))
df["AmtWeek"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Week"])["Amount"].transform(sum)
df["CountWeek"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Week"])["Amount"].transform(len)
df["AvgAmtWeek"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Day"])["Amount"].transform(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x))
df["AmtMonth"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Month"])["Amount"].transform(sum)
df["CountMonth"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Month"])["Amount"].transform(len)
df["AvgAmtMonth"] = df.groupby(["ClientId", "Year", "Day"])["Amount"].transform(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x))
```

Except this gets computationally expensive very quickly to do (mostly) the same grouping every time. **Is there a way to do this more efficiently?**

---

My data is structured as follows where each row represents a single transaction with a clientId, a date (day represents the day of the year), and the amount:

```
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
| ClientId | Year | Month | Week | Day | Amount |
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |     10 |
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     20 |
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     10 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |      5 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |     10 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     30 |
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
```

Whereas I'd like the output to be as follows (Only showing the 3 day columns for better readability):

```
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| ClientId | Year | Month | Week | Day | Amount | AmtDay | CountDay | AvgAmtDay | AmtWeek... Etc. |
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |     10 |     10 |        1 | 10        |                 |
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     20 |     30 |        2 | 15        |                 |
|        1 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     10 |     30 |        2 | 15        |                 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |      5 |     15 |        2 | 7.5       |                 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   1 |     10 |     15 |        2 | 7.5       |                 |
|        2 | 2020 |     1 |    1 |   2 |     30 |     30 |        1 | 30        |                 |
+----------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are different grouping columns need 3 times groupings, here is possible reuse list of columns with aggregation functions in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
L = [('Amt','sum'), ('Count','size'), ('AvgAmt','mean')]
g1 = ["ClientId", "Year","Day"]
g2 = ["ClientId", "Year", "Week"]
g3 = ["ClientId", "Year", "Month"]

df = df.join(df.groupby(g1)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix('Day'), on=g1)
df = df.join(df.groupby(g2)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix('Week'), on=g2)
df = df.join(df.groupby(g3)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix('Month'), on=g3)
```

Or:

```
df = df.join(df.groupby(g1)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix(g1[-1]), on=g1)
df = df.join(df.groupby(g2)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix(g2[-1]), on=g2)
df = df.join(df.groupby(g3)['Amount'].agg(L).add_suffix(g3[-1]), on=g3)
```

Your solution is possible rewrite in nested loop:

```
L = [('Amt','sum'),('Count','size'),('AvgAmt','mean')]
g1 = ["ClientId", "Year","Day"]
g2 = ["ClientId", "Year", "Week"]
g3 = ["ClientId", "Year", "Month"]
groups = [g1, g2, g3]

for g in groups:
    for c, f in L:
        df[f'{c}{g[-1]}'] = df.groupby(g)["Amount"].transform(f)
```

---

```
print (df)
   ClientId  Year  Month  Week  Day  Amount  AmtDay  CountDay  AvgAmtDay  \
0         1  2020      1     1    1      10      10         1       10.0   
1         1  2020      1     1    2      20      30         2       15.0   
2         1  2020      1     1    2      10      30         2       15.0   
3         2  2020      1     1    1       5      15         2        7.5   
4         2  2020      1     1    1      10      15         2        7.5   
5         2  2020      1     1    2      30      30         1       30.0   

   AmtWeek  CountWeek  AvgAmtWeek  AmtMonth  CountMonth  AvgAmtMonth  
0       40          3   13.333333        40           3    13.333333  
1       40          3   13.333333        40           3    13.333333  
2       40          3   13.333333        40           3    13.333333  
3       45          3   15.000000        45           3    15.000000  
4       45          3   15.000000        45           3    15.000000  
5       45          3   15.000000        45           3    15.000000
```